# MYSQL Update value from the division of the result of a query

Tags: mysql

I want to update a field called ratio. For the ratio, I want to calculate it from two values that I get from this query.

```
/*Returns the sum of the latest two entries in two different rows*/
select sum(value) as sum from db.s s
where s.r_id = 76703
group by timeIn
order by timeIn DESC
LIMIT 2;
/*calculate ratio??*/
UPDATE db.r SET ratio = RESULT??
```

The query above gives two rows with two values.
Ratio should be row1/row2
Then update the ratio field on a different table.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a condition on the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost sure that this problem has a way more efficient and clean solution. But, this may also work.

```
UPDATE db.r SET ratio = 
(
 select sum(value) as sum from db.s s
 where s.r_id = 76703
 group by timeIn
 order by timeIn DESC
 LIMIT 1;
)
/
(
 select sum(value) as sum from db.s s
 where s.r_id = 76703
 group by timeIn
 order by timeIn DESC
 LIMIT 1,1;
)
```

Comment: haha. That's what I just came up with (my brute force approach), I do wonder what the more efficient way is. This query took forever...

Answer (score 0):

You could do a rank, and use `CASE` to get the two values;

```
UPDATE r SET ratio = (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c=2 THEN sum ELSE 0 END) /
         SUM(CASE WHEN c=1 THEN sum ELSE 0 END)
  FROM (
    SELECT SUM(value) sum, @c:=@c+1 c
    FROM s, (SELECT @c:=0)a
    WHERE s.r_id = 76703
    GROUP BY timeIn
    ORDER BY timeIn 
    LIMIT 2
  )z
);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/761768/1).